# Clean html input in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

HI guys,

I building an app using CodeIgniter and I came to a problem. I have a form with a textarea in which the user puts his text using a simple editor powered by [jwysiwyg.jquery](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/). The problem is that is need to clean this input of garbage code (link the one that comes with pasting directly from Word).

The form is validated with the form_validation library from CodeIgniter, with this rule:

```
array(
 'field' => 'job[description]',
 'label' => 'Description',
 'rules' => 'trim|required|callback_clean_html'
),
```

Then I have a clean_html method that simply does a:

```
return strip_tags($text,'<a><p><br><strong><em><h3><h4><h5><ul><ol><li>');
```

The problem is that this is simply ignored and the original text gets inserted in the database. The method runs (I've tested). I asume it's because a callback should return TRUE or FALSE, but then xss_clean doesn't return a BOOL. The documentation isn't much help.

Any thoughs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest not using the form_validation.php in the library, but rather write each one individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think form_validation callbacks do need to return a bool. I find that form_validation is most useful when you need to display an error message to a user usually to resubmit the form. Although the prepping functions can be convenient, they don't need to be there to validate. Why not pass the submitted string through the strip_tags function after the form is submitted but before you send it to your db?

Comment: I'll do that, I just thought it would be nice to do all the data prepping  in one place, oh well.

Thank for the respons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `callback_` in the rule? You can do regular PHP functions like `trim` so this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Something aI always do just to be double safe, after setting the rules for the input I also run them through this

```
`$string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`
```

That will strip out the html

I too have run into situations lately where the input totally ignores the rules that have been set.

Answer (score 0):

xss_clean and other CI validation functions return non-bool values.  I just tested the following callback function in CI version 1.7.2:

```
function test_string_change($str)
{
    return "$str **";
}
```

The string was changed successfully using callback_test_string_change.  I know there were some issues with the callback functions in 1.7.0, are you using the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, it should work. Both the "callback_" prefix and the return are correct. Validation methods can return non-bools, which will replace the value. Check the form_validation documentation, it explicitly says that.

So your problem must be in some place of the code that you didn't post.